# Mac iCloud alters Xcode Pods breaking my build

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods

Every couple days to couple weeks I am unable to build my project because Xcode states

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'Fabric'

This also happens with Crashlytics

Now I've narrowed the bug down to some situation in my Pod Folder. To initially fix this I have to delete both Fabric and Crashlytics from the Pod file. Then do a pod install/update.

So the cause of this is, right beside my Fabric and Crashlytics folders there is a little cloud icon.  I assume this is iCloud and it is changing my folders at what appears to be random intervals. <s>How can I unhook these folders from the iCloud?</s>

Or stop iCloud from breaking these folders/pods?

---

I found the meaning of this icon

> It means that the file is stored only in the cloud and not on your computer.

Not sure why this behaviour is active on only these two pods.

---

New Update, I swear this failed before but clicking the cloud downloaded the file from the cloud for me and allowed me to build.

Comment: Are you using this feature? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985

Comment: Yes, and I don't want to just turn this off for my entire mac. As that would be an easy solution.

Comment: Move your Xcode project / pods out of one of the syncing folders, then, and instead store it fully locally on your Mac.

Comment: Do you think there is a reason why it is breaking only these two pods out of my entire project?

Comment: This is really more of a question for [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). A question there about how to force particular folders to always remain local on your Mac would be a good question.

Comment: Well even just to solve why this behavior is breaking only two pods rather than forcing everything local might be a better solution. I'll consider asking this question there though, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Add an empty file called `.nosync` and iCloud will ignore that directory and all of its subdirectories.

It seems like you're syncing your desktop and documents folders with iCloud Drive. The easiest way would be to move your Xcode project to another directory.

Maybe look into iCloud having an ignore list that makes it omit certain files.

You can also add pre-build actions to delete and redownload your pods in the scheme editor menu. This [GitHub Repo](https://gist.github.com/acrookston/55d69a16cd5363426dbf7a3d6a9ee6ce) explains what I'm talking about.

Comment: This ended up working, but only because I found a way to ignore this specific project folder. Here is a link I found to handle this easily. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/261437

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are storing your Xcode project and Pods folder into a folder syncing to iCloud (which could be Desktop or Documents folder).

The problem might occur for a number of reasons and I'd bet it's the syncing mechanism getting stressed by the build/pods system.

To address the issue:

- create a folder "Development" in your User folder (for example /Users/Charles/Development) -> this folder will not be synced with iCloud
- move your project to the Development folder
- drag the folder to the Finder sidebar for easy access
- if you were using iCloud to share the project across multiple Mac, go to BitBucket/GitHub and use a git repository instead. If you don't want to use Git but fancy cloud sync, use Dropbox or disable Mac storage optimisation in iCloud Drive settings

Comment: Great answer, the other one ended up solving my issue after some digging. If this comes up on any other projects I might check out this angle, thanks!.