# Xcode Workspace Won't Open

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode14

I added a cocoapod while Xcode 14.2 was open, and it caused Xcode to freeze. I had to force close and reopen. Xcode then says "Loading MyProjectName..." and it hangs there forever without ever showing code or files. None of the following attempts has fixed the problem:

1. Restarting Xcode
2. Restarting my computer
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling all cocoapods
4. Deleting and recloning the whole git repository
5. Deleting Derived Data
6. Deleting the Saved State for Xcode

Note that other projects still open fine - it's just this one workspace that causes Xcode to load forever and freeze.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There was absolutely nothing indicating this was the case, but it turns out my problem was the same as indicated here: [Mac iCloud alters Xcode Pods breaking my build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739295/mac-icloud-alters-xcode-pods-breaking-my-build)

Had to add .nosync to the parent folder of the repository. When I reopened the workspace and waited about 10 seconds suddenly files began showing up again.